Spectral sequences that are not obtain from Grothendieck's one
Can one find an example of a spectral sequence which cannot be constructed using Grothedieck spectral sequence?
Warning: I'm not asking example of spectral sequence that can be constructed without the Grothendieck spectral sequence. I'm asking of spectral sequence we can't obtain from Grothendieck's one.

I'm not sure I would know how to prove that a given spectral sequence can't be obtained from another one. Some possible candidates in this case: the Bockstein spectral sequence, the spectral sequence from a filtered chain complex, the spectral sequence(s) from a double complex. Your question might be clearer if you listed examples of spectral sequences which are known to be constructible from the Grothendieck ss.

I agree with John Palmieri's comment that this is probably not an optimally posed question. There's an "obvious" obstruction in that Grothendieck spectral sequences are always first-quadrant, so I guess your question would technically be answered by providing any meaningful class of spectral sequences that isn't first-quadrant. I'm not sure if that's what you're really looking for, though.

Dear @Thorgott, this is precisely what I am looking for. I don't know what to do about my question. I agrre that question is not well asked. By "obtain  from Grothendieck ss" I mean that we can build two functor such that the ss is the Grothendieck one (apply to these functors). Before I edit please tell me if it is now clear enough :)

There are plenty of spectral sequences that do not "naturally" come as Grothendieck spectral sequences. If those could be obtained as Grothendieck spectral sequences in some abstract manner, it would most likely be for tautological rather than insightful reasons. In any case, I do not know a method to tell whether this is possible for a given first quadrant spectral sequence or not.
However, as clarified in the comments, you are happy with spectral sequences that are not first quadrant (which all Grothendieck spectralsequences are). An example of such a spectral sequence is the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence. For any generalized cohomology theory $h^{\bullet}$ and any CW-pair $(X,A)$, there is a natural right half-plane cohomological spectral sequence $E_2^{pq}=H^{p}(X,A;h^q)$ (this is singular cohomology with coefficients in the groups $h^q=h^q(\mathrm{pt})$) that is conditionally convergent to $h^{p+q}(X,A)$. In general, a cohomology theory need not vanish in negative degrees, so this will be a bona fide right half-plane spectral sequence. For example, one can take $h^{\bullet}$ to be complex $K$-theory and $X$ to be finite-dimensional, in which case the spectral sequence strongly converges and is contained in a (typically infinite) vertical strip of the plane.
